Why are my low-voltage landscape lights flashing?
I installed a 300 W low-voltage transformer and new wiring and 36.8 W lights in my yard. When the transformer kicks on at the time, the lights flash one time five seconds. I disconnected each light individually in the remaining ones still flashed.
I checked the voltage at the end of the run line and it was right around 2.8 volts. Then checked the voltage coming out of the transformer while the run wire and lights were still connected to it and it was putting out 2.8 V just when it flashed. When the lights were not flashing, it was zero volts. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Sounds like dodgy behavior from dodgy electronics. But it's hard to tell with the (lack of) detail you've given; if you can identify the transformer, length of wiring, expected voltage, and the rest of testing you've done, you might get (better) answers.

Could be a short in the yard wire or a bad controller. What is the voltage at the transformer when the yard wire is completely disconnected? If you wire one light through a set of temporary wires to the transformer, does the light work? If not, what is the transformer voltage while the temporary test setup is connected?

Are the transformer & lights all UL/ETL listed? If not, chuck 'em and start over.

It’s a 300 watt harbor breeze  transformer from Lowes. The 3 lights are also Harbor Breeze and are 6.8 watt each. The wiring is low voltage 12/2 and the run is approximately 60-70 ft. I checked the volts at the end of the run and it was 2.8 when the  lights flashed on (every 5 seconds) and zero volts when the lights were not flashing. I got the same readings at the transformer. According to the paperwork the transformer will show 0 volts if there are no lights attached to the run wire, minimum of 10 amp load required.

It’s all new and just installed two days ago. I also plugged the transformer in another outlet that was not GFCI just as a test and still glasses once every 5 seconds. The wire is also new and has not been buried. Checked the wire and all appears ok.

A) Please [edit] your question to improve formatting and to include the details you've put down here in the comments. B) Who did the install - you or an electrician?

Flashing lights means crowbar, which is a word for a special protective circuit in the power supply that prevents it from overload.  https://www.analog.com/en/resources/glossary/crowbar.html The supply is already designed to shut down in case of a short circuit, so the crowbar circuit causes a short when it sees an overload.  Then with the load gone, the power supply resets and tries again over and over.  So you have either an overload or a short.  Long wire runs of low voltage can add enough voltage drop that a short acts like an overload.

Quote from comment, emphasis added:

According to the paperwork the transformer will show 0 volts if there are no lights attached to the run wire, minimum of 10 amp load required.

Sounds like your three 6.8W lamps (or unknown number of 36.8W lamps, which is unclear as a comment says one thing, and the question says another) (at unmentioned voltage, but probably 12) don't meet the minimum load of this power supply.
However, if the unspecified other than brand/wattage and source supply is this one, the minimum load is 10W, not 10A, and blinking is listed as most likely caused by the photoeye getting lit, or a bad connection, or too much wattage.
Too much wattage can be caused by bad wiring (a partial short circuit.)
Suggested Diagnostic Tests.

Disconnect the lights and the transformer from the wiring, leaving all other connections as they were. Check resistance between the wires in the cable. Should be infinite.
Now short the wires in the cable at the furthest light position. Check the resistance again. Should now be about 0.22Ω
disconnect the wires at that light location again and short each of the others, repeating the resistance measurement at the transformer end of the wiring.
Take the disconnected lights and connect them directly to the transformer with a short piece of cable.


Are these LED lights? If so, flashing rather than continuous may mean they aren't getting enough power. Try bringing the light to the transformer and connecting them with short wires; does it still blink? Check that the transformer is providing the voltage those lights call for. Check that the footage at the light is correct; you could have a bad connection or a damaged cable.

The thing wants 10W minimum and 300W maximum so your 37W setup should work.
If you are using the light sensor you might have some of the landscape lights pointed at it.    Cover the light sensor to see if that solves the problem.
You should not be reading 2.8V anywhere ever.  You should read 12V near the transformer when it's on.   Maybe less at the other end of the cable, and hopefully not much less.  You need to experiment with the lights using a short piece of the cable.
